# Unable to start embedded Tomcat Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am new to microservices & trying to create eureka netflix naming server.Added all dependency whihc are required but still receiving an error saying unable to start embeded tomcat server due to no class def found for org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2.

Error :

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) [spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.pavan.microservices.namingserver.NamingServerApplication.main(NamingServerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:473) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:206) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/XMLInputFactory2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:175) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:170) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/XMLInputFactory2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/stax2/XMLInputFactory2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:145) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadFromParent(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.doLoadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.util.xml.StaxUtils.createDefensiveInputFactory(StaxUtils.java:77) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.util.xml.StaxUtils.createDefensiveInputFactory(StaxUtils.java:67) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder$XmlObjectMapperInitializer.create(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:911) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:669) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.java:52) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.<init>(FormContentFilter.java:61) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedFormContentFilter.java:29) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.formContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    ... 107 common frames omitted
```

NamingServerApplication.java :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class NamingServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NamingServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties :

```
spring.application.name=naming-server
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependency hasn't been properly installed.

If your project is built with Maven add this to pom.xml

```
<!-- 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If it's Gradle project add following to build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', name: 'stax2-api', version: '3.0.1'
```